# What is use of 'parameters' option in binding object?

Tags: sapui5

In the code below, what is the significance of `parameters` option and `select` option within it?

I have looked into API but to avail nothing.

```
<List id="list" 
    items="{
        path: '/PurchaseOrders',
        sorter: [{
            path: 'ChangedAt', 
            descending: true
        }, {
            path: 'POId', 
            descending: false
        }],
        parameters: {
            select: 'POId,OrderedByName,SupplierName,GrossAmount,CurrencyCode,ChangedAt,ItemCount'
        }
    }">
    ...
</List>
```

Comment: Where did you find that piece of code?

Comment: It is Sample application in SAP web IDE *Approve Purchase Order*, You can get it by *New>Project from Sample Application* and within that look into *S2_PurchaseOrders.view.xml*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the select property you can tell the server to return just a subset of  entity properties. This is useful if you have large entities with a lot of properties, but want to display only some of them, e.g. in a table. This works only if you are using an ODataModel and thus an ODataListBinding.

In general the parameters argument is used to pass implementation specific parameters to the binding while having a common API for all model implementations, i.e. all implementations of a ListBinding have the following signature:

- oModel (the model which holds the data)
- sPath (the binding path)
- oContext (the binding context)
- aSorters (sorters to be applied)
- aFilters (filters to be applied)
- mParameters (additional parameters which depend on the model implementation and are not necessarily supported by all of them)